# Trying to export from a multivalued attribute "Proxyaddresses" to csv

Tags: powershell

Trying to export from a multivalued attribute "Proxyaddresses"  from multiple OUs to csv. i am getting "Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.ADPropertyValueCollection"

Here is my code,

Thanks

"ou=no gpo,ou=Staff, ou=offices,dc=ddddd,dc=ca",
"ou=Staff win10,dc=ddddd,dc=ca" | ForEach-Object {

```
Get-ADUser -Filter * -SearchBase $_ -Properties *
```

}| select name, @{Name=’proxyAddresses’;Expression={[string]::join(“;”, ($_.proxyAddresses))}} | Export-Csv c:\temp\all_proxyaddresses.csv -NoTypeInformation

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

$a= "ou=no gpo,ou=Staff, ou=offices,dc=ddddd,dc=ca", "ou=Staff win10,dc=ddddd,dc=ca"

$a| ForEach-Object { Get-ADUser -Filter * -SearchBase $_ -Properties *}| select name, @{Name=’proxyAddresses’;Expression={$_.proxyAddresses -join ';'}} | Export-Csv c:\temp\all_proxyaddresses.csv -NoTypeInformation

Comment: please use the code formatting facility to highlight your code example and make it more readable

Comment: That worked, thank you!